# Execute event after object value changes

Tags: c#, .net

I an using C# and .NET 3.5.
I am trying to do an object Validator that receives any kind of controllers and validates that the user is using it correctly. For example, the Validator receives a Textbox, the user changes the Text of the Textbox, the validator will notice this and will execute a check on it.

Is there anyway to do this? An event that is triggered as soon as one object from a list is changed?

Comment: Desktop or web? For desktop you can use the TextBox.TextChanged event.

Comment: Desktop. The Validator will only receive the Textbox.Text property so it wouldnt work that out. I want the Validator to trigger an event when any of its given objects change their values (mostly strings from a textbox)

Comment: Please post some sample code to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: There is no sample code, my doubt is if it's possible to add custom events to an object and how D:

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do this. Read about two of them at

[User Input Validation in Windows Forms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229603%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)
and
[ErrorProvider Component (Windows Forms)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/95ysxkwy%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

Comment: The thing is that this Validator will show up every single error that the objects value have in a Textbox. For example, if you have two textboxes, then there will an Error Textbox that will show both error messages. What I wanted to do is an object that revalidates the field each time an object value is changed. Something like the Observer pattern.

Comment: Well then you should consider TextBox.TextChanged or TextBox.TextChanging as Maritim suggested.